# TextEdit refuses to modify a file in /Users/Shared owned by another user despite mode 666

Tags: macos, permission, textedit

I have a text file in /Users/Shared that I would like to be editable by all users on my Mac. The Get Info window shows that everyone has read and write access, and when I open the file with TextEdit on a non-owner account, the title bar does not state that the file is locked. Yet when I attempt to save my edits, I'm faced with the "The document could not be [saved / autosaved]. You don't have permission" popups.

I've tried adding the non-owner user to the permissions list in the Get Info window. No dice.

Outputs from `ls` (with names edited):

```
$ ls -l /Users/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x+ 14 Guest        _guest   476  7 Apr 11:14 Guest
drwxrwxrwt  45 root         wheel   1530 12 Apr 17:40 Shared
drwxr-xr-x+ 15 fileowner    staff    510 22 Feb 12:49 fileowner
drwxr-xr-x+ 17 admin        staff    578 21 Dec 10:55 admin
$ ls -l /Users/Shared/Links.txt 
-rw-rw-rw-@ 1 fileowner  wheel  619 25 Feb 19:44 /Users/Shared/Links.txt
```

I can reproduce this behavior on two separate machines, one running 10.8 and the other 10.9, but not on the one running 10.6.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Notice that the permission string for /Users/Shared ends with a 't'. This indicates that the sticky bit is set for that directory. According to "man 8 sticky",

> ```
>  A directory whose `sticky bit' is set becomes an append-only directory,
>  or, more accurately, a directory in which the deletion of files is
>  restricted.  A file in a sticky directory may only be removed or renamed
>  by a user if the user has write permission for the directory and the user
>  is the owner of the file, the owner of the directory, or the super-user.
> ```

I suspect that when TextEdit tries to save a file, it first attempts to rename or remove the old file. But in a directory with the sticky bit set, only the owner can do this. Hence, the permission-based failure.

You could test this by trying something like this as user Guest

```
echo " " >> /Users/Shared/Links.txt
```

If this is successful, it shows that Guest can write to the file and that TextEdit must be renaming or removing, not just rewriting the file.

Comment: Welcome, we like detailed answers like this one.

Comment: Your terminal command went through without a hitch, so it does look like the implementation of file versioning since 10.7 uses renaming and/or (re)moving, rather than overwriting. Thanks!

Comment: @Buscar: Thanks for the welcome. Glad I could contribute.

epimorphic: Thanks for letting me know what happened. It's always nice to hear that one's idea worked. :)