# Edit text file in a folder owned by a different user on macOS? I have system admin password

Tags: macos, permission, filesystem, mojave, text-editor

How can I access and edit a text file found in a folder owned by another user?

I am in the original user account setup for this [macOS Mojave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Mojave) installation, and have the system admin password. So I perform [`su` or `sudo`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo) as needed.

I do *not* want to change the [permissions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions#Traditional_Unix_permissions) on the containing folder nor the text file. So [this Question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/127388/17907) does not apply.

I just want to:

1. **Open** the text file, preferably in *TextEdit.app*.
2. **Edit the text**.
3. **Save** the file.

Bonus: Be able to navigate the folder hierarchy and see file listings using the Finder or via [`cd`/`ls`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cd_(command)) command-line tools in the console ([Terminal.app](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_(macOS))).

---

I tried `sudo cd /path/to/protected_folder`, and entered admin password as prompted, without error. But then `ls` shows me my starting directory rather than the `/path/to/protected_folder` folder contents.

I tried `sudo open /path/to/protected_folder` which does bring the Finder to the front, but with the protected folder showing and selected, but not opened.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the path to the file that you want to edit, you can use:

`sudo -e /path/to/file/name/here.txt`

and it will allow you to edit it with your $EDITOR of choice.

If you want to use the Open dialog box, you might *think* this will work:

`sudo /Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents/MacOS/TextEdit`

But that fails with an error:

"Illegal instruction: 4"

However, [BBEdit](http://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/) will work:

`sudo /Applications/BBEdit.app/Contents/MacOS/BBEdit`

And [you can use BBEdit for free](http://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/download.html).

Oh, and both methods keep the original ownership of the file and permissions intact.

Comment: This answer needs more explanation. Basically you can edit with sudo and a terminal based editor. A gui one like texted it won't work with sudo.

Comment: Um… a) BBEdit is not a terminal-based editor, and b) GUI apps can and do work with `sudo`. Just like I demonstrated in my answer. The fact that TextEdit doesn't is an exceptional case, which is why I mentioned it specifically.